# How to make a data class Parcelable in a Kotlin library in multi-module Android project?

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, multi-module, android-multi-module

I am trying to break my android `app` into smaller gradle modules (for now `data` and `model` modules). I want to keep my `model` module as a Kotlin library because it will only contains data classes. But some of those data classes are `Parcelable`. To use `Parcelable` in `model` module I will have to convert it to an Android library which I am trying to avoid.

One solution that I can think of is to create another class in `app` module with the exact same structure as the original class in `model` module and then write a mapper function from one class to another. But it looks like a lot of boilerplate just to make them `Parcelable`.

Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: Maybe on each model class have a toJSON() method that returns a JSONObject, or a String, and a constructor that excepts JSONObject (or a string)?. This will require a call to toJSON() whenever you want to encode and create an object using the JSON constructor to decode.

Comment: @gioravered Are you saying that I shouldn't make it `Parcelable` and instead use the Json string to pass the model between screens?

Comment: I'm saying that if you want to completely "free" you code from Android then you can't use Parcelable.